Could not autowire. No beans of 'NativeWebRequest' type found
Following the Doing API First Development guide for JHipster (in fact I rewrote the guide to be more explanatory and opened an MR), yet I'm still faced with this error in the Delegate Implementation class.

Either this is 1) an IntelliJ error, 2) an assumption gap in the documentation (that I will gladly add to the MR), or 3) there's a missing starter or dependency. For example, the S3Template is provided by the io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-starter-s3 and works as expected.
This is tangentially related to How and where to add new bean in spring application generated by JHipster. The guide, as is and in the MR, continues to make the assumption, and I quote:

If you provide the NativeWebRequest bean to the delegate interface, then basic example bodies will be returned for the methods that have not been overridden (still with a 501 HTTP status code).

I should point out this works as expected, but the resolution of the bean bothers me when working in the project.
What am I missing here?
